# Synthetic collaboration diagrams in Doxygen?

Tags: diagram, doxygen, hidden, collaboration

In Doxygen, I would like to have more synthetic collaboration diagrams, i.e. where just the class name or just its public member functions are shown.

I do not want to disable the analysis of what a class is made of, I just do not want to see it in the diagram.

In the documentation I could not find a way to do it. It would be a good way to have an overview of a large diagram that could more easily fit on the screen.

How can I do it?